# How to check if player enters/exits a tile on the tilemap?

Tags: godot, gdscript

I'm working on a project where once you step out of a tile, that tile becomes a lava tile.
(meaning you can only step on a tile once, making for some interesting levels.) But I cant figure out how to check if the player exits a tile. Please help. Thanks

Comment: Could you add some information? Is this 2D or 3D? And are you using a tilemap? If so, which mode? Standing "on" a tile also looks different depending on the genre (platformer vs tactics for example).

Comment: 2D, tilemap, square, topdown...

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at `Area2D`. It provides you with enter and exit events.
Take a look at the links below.

[Physics introduction](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/physics/physics_introduction.html)

[Area2D](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_area2d.html#class-area2d)

[Area2D tutorial](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/physics/using_area_2d.html)

Answer (score 0):

`TileMap` has a function to tell you which tile a given position corresponds to.

Assuming you are in your player script, you can find which tile you are standing on with:

```
tile_map.local_to_map(position)
```

Now it's just a matter of saving the current_tile in a variable, and then check if the tile still equals `current_tile`, if not, we changed tile and it is time for `current_tile` to go lava.

However, this may be pretty inefficient to run every cycle, so I'm happy to be pointed towards a better solution (researching this led me here).